# Help with INSERT INTO..SELECT

Tags: mysql, insert

I'm inserting a large number of rows into Table_A.  Table_A includes a B_ID column which points to Table_B.B_ID.

Table B has just two columns: Table_B.B_ID (the primary key) and Table_B.Name.

I know the value for every Table_A field I'm inserting except B_ID.  I only know the corresponding Table_B.Name.  So how can I insert multiple rows into Table_A?

Here's a pseudocode version of what I want to do:

```
REPLACE INTO Table_A (Table_A.A_ID, Table_A.Field, Table_A.B_ID) VALUES
(1, 'foo', [SELECT B_ID FROM Table_B WHERE Table_B.Name = 'A'),
(2, 'bar', [SELECT B_ID FROM Table_B WHERE Table_B.Name = 'B'),...etc
```

Comment: Where is `1`, `'foo'`, etc. coming from?  It can probably be accomplished with a join if these fields are read from a table somewhere as well.

Comment: 1 and 'foo' are from PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to do things like this when deploying scripts to a production environment where Ids differed in environments. Otherwise it's probably easier to type out the ID's

```
REPLACE INTO table_a (table_a.a_id, table_a.field, table_a.b_id) 
SELECT 1, 'foo', b_id, FROM table_b WHERE name = 'A' 
UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'bar', b_id, FROM table_b WHERE name = 'B'
```

Comment: You are missing a `SELECT` after `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 0):

If the values:

```
(1, 'foo', 'A'),
(2, 'bar', 'B'),
```

come from a `(SELECT ...)`

you can use this:

```
INSERT INTO Table_A
    ( A_ID, Fld, B_ID)

SELECT Data.A_ID
     , Data.Field
     , Table_B.B_ID
    FROM (SELECT ...) As Data
        JOIN Table_B
            ON Table_B.Name = Data.Name
```

---

If not, you can insert them into a temporary table and then use the above, replacing `(SELECT ...)` with `TemporaryTable`.

```
CREATE TABLE HelpTable
    ( A_ID int
    , Fld varchar(200)
    , Name varchar(200)
    ) ;

INSERT INTO HelpTable
VALUES
(1, 'foo', 'A'),
(2, 'bar', 'B'), etc...
;

INSERT INTO Table_A
    ( A_ID, Field, B_ID)
SELECT HelpTable.A_ID
     , HelpTable.Fld
     , Table_B.B_ID
    FROM HelpTable 
        JOIN Table_B
            ON Table_B.Name = HelpTable.Name
;

DROP TABLE HelpTable ;
```

Comment: Only 'A' and 'B' are selected

Comment: "If the value...come from a (SELECT ...)".  Only the B_ID comes from a select (based on 'A' and 'B' here)

Comment: OK. So, I think that you can try the second option with the `HelpTable`